# Cancel command in bash DEBUG trap

Tags: bash

I'm trapping DEBUG in bash with:

```
trap 'python /trap.py --command "$BASH_COMMAND"' DEBUG
```

Is there a command I can execute within `trap.py` which will prevent the command which trapped from being executed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's what the `extdebug` option is for (among other things).

When set:

> If the command run by the 'DEBUG' trap returns a non-zero
> value, the next command is skipped and not executed

So all you need to do is set that option `shopt -s extdebug` and have your `trap.py` return with a non-zero exit status if you want the command to be skipped.

```
$ bash -xc 'shopt -s extdebug; trap "[[ \$BASH_COMMAND != uname ]]" DEBUG; echo test; uname'
+ shopt -s extdebug
+ trap '[[ $BASH_COMMAND != uname ]]' DEBUG
++ [[ echo test != uname ]]
+ echo test
test
++ [[ uname != uname ]]
```

You may want to check the `bash` manual for other implications of setting that option.